# Stop automatic Zbar camera rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera, autorotate, zbar

I'm using a zbar reader view controller and when I rotate the iPhone quickly enough that Portrait (up) goes straight to Portrait Upside Down (and vice versa) or I go straight from Landscape Left to Right (and vice versa) then the camera rotates 180 degrees. I am using IOS 6, 7 and 8 and am using Objective C.

How do I prevent this camera rotation from happening?

Comment: and this problem happens under iOS 6, 7 and 8??  or only under certain ones (e.g. 6 & 7)?

Comment: it is happening with 6 and 7 on iPhones but I can't confirm on 8 on device as I don't have access to one at the moment.

Comment: I'm having the same problem... any luck?